# Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @49c595f

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

I have updated Android Studio IDE to Flamingo and I tried to run My App but I got error,

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @49c595fe

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:142)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
```

I'm using JDK version is 11

what is the problem? can anyone explain how to solve this problem.

Comment: Flamingo uses JDK 17 and many plugins or modules could not be compatible because them could use internal/private methods that, usually, could not be possibile to use. You can try to read this: https://modthefuture.com/execution-failed-appprocessdebugmainmanifest-react-native-android-fix/?utm_content=cmp-true